# Showing propagation in ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a very simple linear First Order Homogeneous Differential Equation with time but this makes me ponder upon the definition of derivative and integral.
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -H(t)y$$ where $y, H(t)$ are scalar.

I know that propagating of $y$ from $t$ to $t+\Delta t$ should have:
$$y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)$$, $\Delta t$ is small, (but may not be small enough to cancel the second order of taylor series.) But I also hope to show it.

**Method 1:**

From first principle, I have
$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)}{\Delta t} = -H(t)y(t)$$.

This gives in the limit of small $\Delta t$,
$$y(t+\Delta t) = y(t) - H(t)y(t)\Delta t = (1 - H(t)\Delta t)y(t)$$

This only gives the first order taylor expansion of $e^{-H(t)\Delta t}$. Does it **imply** $$y(t+\Delta t) = e^{-H(t)\Delta t}y(t)$$? There are many function having the first order taylor expansion as $(1 - H(t)\Delta t)$. Worse still, how can I "get" $y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)$ from here?

**Method 2:**

Indefinite Integral
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -H(t)y \\ \implies \frac{dy}{y} = -H(t)dt 
\implies \int \frac{dy}{y} = \int -H(t)dt \\ \ln y = - \int -H(t)dt + C$$ where C is a constant.
This gives
$$y(t) = Ce^{- \int H(t)dt}$$ I am confused here. Does this imply $$y(t + \Delta t) = Ce^{- \int -H(t + \Delta t)dt}$$ If it is, how can I show $$y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t)dt}y(t)$$ as all I know is $$\frac{y(t + \Delta t)}{y(t)} = \frac{e^{- \int H(t + \Delta t)dt}}{e^{- \int H(t)dt}}$$?

**Method 3:**
Definite Integral
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -H(t)y \\ \implies \frac{dy}{y} = -H(t)dt 
\implies \int_{y(t)}^{y(t+\Delta t)} \frac{dy}{y} = \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t} -H(t)dt \\ \ln y(t+\Delta t) - \ln y(t) = - \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t)dt \\ y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t')dt'}y(t)$$ I did it. But why I cannot do the same in method 1 and method 2?

I also hope to know, if by going to Riemann Sum $$\int_{t}^{(t+\Delta t)}H(t)dt = \lim_{\delta t \rightarrow 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{(t+\Delta t)/(\delta t)}(\delta t)H(k\delta t)- \sum_{k=0}^{(t)/(\delta t)}(\delta t)H(k\delta t)\right)$$, can I also show $y(t+\Delta t) = e^{- \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}H(t)dt}y(t)$ in my method 1 and 2?

Comment: Why method 1 fails follows from the definition of a derivative - it's precisely the best linear approximation to how the function changes when moving from $t$ to $t + \Delta t$. Consequently, it won't capture terms of $O((\Delta t)^n)$ for $n>1$.

Comment: You won't get *exact* equality by any of these kinds of things. If you want exact equality you're probably going to need to exploit the fundamental theorem or full series expansion. The latter will be much uglier than you might expect...

Comment: @stochasticboy321  but why do they (method 1 and real solution) both imply the same differential equation?

Comment: integrate $\frac{y'}{y}(t) = H(t)$

Comment: @kww Do they? Differentiate the expression in method one w.r.t. $t$, holding $\Delta t$ constant. You clearly get a different equation. Only in the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$ do these agree, but this is the regime where the derivative is a good description of how the function varies.

Comment: As to method 2, note that $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ has no well defined meaning as a function. It's instead a set of functions which are equivalent up to an additive real term, and you can't treat these as numbers or do operations over them unless you fix this term - until then the expressions you have above have no meaning. However, fixing this term is equivalent to determining an initial value, which is equivalent to positing a definite integral!

Comment: @stochasticboy321 but in differential equation isn't the limit of $\Delta t$ is taken?

Comment: Certainly, but that's not the solution you've constructed, right? In essence, the argument above is saying that if you take $\Delta t \to 0$, then the two solutions are equal, but not unless you work in that regime.